# Who should moderate our site?

Tags: discussion, 7-questions, moderation

Raspberry Pi StackExchange has been in public beta for almost a week now, and soon it will be time for us to get our first crop of moderators. As explained in the ["Moderator Pro Tempore" blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/):

> About a week into the public beta, we will seek out members who are
>   deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who:
>
> - Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent
>     participation.
> - Show an interest in their meta’s community-building
>     activities.
> - Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their
>     fellow community members in everything they write.
> - Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Each beta site has three moderators on a temporary, short-term appointment.

Moderators Pro Tem focus and expedite the essential needs of each new site, both in terms of [regular moderator activies](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) and as a liaison of the growing community with the Stack Exchange team. By the end of Beta, the community will be better suited to hold their own elections.

The moderators pro tempore will ultimately be selected by Stack Exchange Although during beta moderators will, the purpose of this post is to seek out and propose candidates:

- Each nomination should be posted as an answer and it should include (at minimum) a link to the user's main and meta profile so we can check out their activity.
- Self nominations are encouraged, step up if you feel you can help.
- If you are nominated by someone else you should edit the answer and let us know if you accept or decline (explanation optional). If a nominee declines we will not delete the answer, as to not have someone else nominate them again.
- The nominations are not binding to Stack Exchange or the nominees.
- Before nominating someone or accept / decline a nomination, you should read [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) thoroughly to find out what's generally expected from moderators.

If you would like to learn more about the role, please drop into our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3748/the-supreme-council-of-the-pi) where you can ask about the role from other moderators (they appear with a blue name in the chat room). Another chatroom called [The Assembly](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2691/the-assembly) was created specifically for users and moderators to discuss moderation activities, moderators from all over the network are there to answer your questions.

Comment: Why did this question get closed? I'm curious.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson It is no longer relevant, as mods have been selected.

Comment: Can I nominate another user somehow?

Comment: @AwesomeUser I'm afraid there can only exist three pro-tem mods.

Comment: @Jivings ok thanks anyways.

Answer (score 15):

I would like to nominate myself for the position. Here are my credentials:

---

[profile for Jivings on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/133139.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/133139)


[image: profile for Jivings at Raspberry Pi, Q&A for users and developers of hardware and software for Raspberry Pi]

[image: profile for Jivings at Raspberry Pi Meta, Q&A about the site for users and developers of hardware and software for Raspberry Pi]

---

I am a recent Computer Science Graduate. My forte is in programming and Linux.
However, as can be seen from my Raspberry Pi answers, I am keen to answer other questions as best I can.

Although I have had no experience moderating on StackExchange before, I believe that I can be a valued member of the community helping to shape our site. Most importantly, I am willing to learn from the more experienced mods of the StackExchange world.

Currently I am working on site improvements and publishing, having recently achieved booster and two announcer badges. I am also very active answering, commenting and reviewing.

---

As well as the site, I am passionate about the Raspberry Pi. I have clocked up a stupid number of hours experimenting with my little electronic friend. Although I mainly hack about with Arch Linux, I am looking to understand GPIO programming to complement my existing knowledge.

---

If I am appointed, know that I will always be interested in *listening*. I also enjoy taking care of the site; reading wiki edits, retagging and discussing our controversial topics. I'll be happy to take this further by dealing with flags and disputes.

Appointed or not, know that I will be working towards making the Raspberry Pi StackExchange a great place to be. Hopefully allowing it to grow and flourish.

Comment: I don't like that you asked the question *and* nominated yourself.  -1.

Comment: @finnw: All questions and answers here belong to the community. Whomever asked the question is immaterial.

Comment: But you still have the ability to accept an answer (conflict of interest.)

Comment: @finnw Well then this is a problem you have with the selection process, not my nomination.

Answer (score 7):

I, dunsmoreb, nominate myself, dunsmoreb, as a community moderator, dunsmoreb.

---

[SE Rep: 3.9k http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/341481.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/341481/dunsmoreb)
[image: RPi Rep: 994]
[image: Meta RPi Rep: 994]

---

While I may not answer the most questions on the main Raspberry Pi site, I am very active in editing. I've edited over 100 posts and 25 tag wikis. I believe that  the quality of questions is a reflection on how much a community cares about a particular subject, and ergo I try to edit and retag questions and answers to their best.

I am also very active on the meta site. I love discussing topics related to the site and it's community on meta. As exhibited by me being ranked top user by participation and votes on meta. I've also had experience with Stack Overflow Meta, so I know the rules and expectations of meta.

---

If I were nominated as a community moderator, I would listen to my fellow community members and see what their opinion on issues are. As I feel a community is more successful when **all** of its members are involved in it's success. Oh yeah, and I would: handle flags, suggested edits, and etc.; I guess. =P

Either way, I will not stop contributing to the community no matter the decision. As I believe this community is a great idea that has even greater potential. Thank you for listening to my rambling! =D

Answer (score 7):

I would also like to nominate myself.

---

[profile for Alex Chamberlain on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/931546.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/931546/alex-chamberlain)

[image: profile for Alex Chamberlain at Raspberry Pi, Q&A for users and developers of hardware and software for Raspberry Pi]


[image: profile for Alex Chamberlain at Raspberry Pi Meta, Q&A about the site for users and developers of hardware and software for Raspberry Pi]

---

I am a recent Mathematics graduate, with A levels in Electronics and Computing. I have a job lined up in November as a software developer, and have loads of time to kill before then! I want to make an active contribution to our growing community.

Similar to others, I don't have previous moderating experience from other SE sites, but I am very willing to learn, and I have been very active on the Beta. I have been able to apply my knowledge of Linux - which I use on a day to day basis - to the specific case of the Pi.

I like make sure the site is putting its best foot forward and demonstrates its valuable contribution to the wider Raspberry Pi community. I have done this by carefully editing posts and reviewing others' suggested edits.

I look forward to contributing actively to the community in the future.

Comment: -1 because you have asked a lot of subjective and borderline-offtopic questions and I want the site to be stricter (to make it more attractive to experts.)

Comment: @finnw I've also written 2 extended question/answers.

Comment: And you've closed [my first question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/893/470) on this site as a duplicate, when the question asked was related only because they both used the word bluetooth in the title. And after I edited the question to make my intent more clear, you changed it back, so you could still vote to close. Not what I would consider a moderator worthy response.

Comment: @zenbike Please read my comments. I VTCd as "Not Constructive", but there were 3 VTCs as "Exact Duplicate", so that's what gets published. Furthermore, if you look at the edits, I made a single rollback, which you reversed. I did not make 2. Happy to chat about this zenbike, because I think you have misunderstood.

Comment: No, I didn't misunderstand, as our chat has made more clear to me. You don't have the flexibility to be a mod.

Comment: I have certainly learnt that I should have contacted the OP before casting my VTC.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to nominate myself for the position.

---

[profile for jandjorgensen on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/194719.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/194719)


[image: profile for jandjorgensen at Raspberry Pi, Q&A for users and developers of hardware and software for Raspberry Pi]


[image: profile for jandjorgensen at Raspberry Pi Meta, Q&A about the site for users and developers of hardware and software for Raspberry Pi]

---

I may not yet have quite so high of a reputation score as some other users, but I have been reasonably active in the beta, especially in the meta and in discussions regarding on-topic and off-topic questions.  I've followed the site from definition phase into the beta, and have a general idea of the direction the community is headed.  I've earned the Convention badge, a requirement of moderation on Stack Overflow, and began a lot of the initial necessary discussion for a successful beta.

In addition to participation in the site, I'm also highly interested in outreach.  This may not, strictly speaking, be the responsibility of moderators, though speaking from an official capacity may give outreach some more weight.  I think as the site grows and gains popularity it will be important to directly contact the foundation and open a one-on-one dialog with their PR representative to discuss any possibility of their support or participation.

## Why you should vote for me

- Upon appointment as a moderator I would immediately set aside my own personal convictions for the direction of the site in favor of representing the community as a whole.  Thus far a lot of my input has been discussion and disagreement with other beta users.  While the discussion could continue, **my intervention and actions themselves, as well as the reasoning and explanation for these actions, would be as a representative of the community at-large**.
- In representing the community, I would provide guidance with **respect and fairness.**  If an action is representative of the site's community I would not hesitate to do it, but would always couple this firmness with respect.
- I would be careful to make sure I comment, in detail, on posts that I either take an action on or consider taking an action on.  Since my participation in the Stack Exchange community as a whole, I have paid close attention to Robert Cartaino's example in doing this and would follow it carefully.  The difference between a frustrating experience and an understanding one for a user can be as simple as **polite, prompt communication**.
- Though I do not post answers, questions or comments every day, I make sure to visit the site at least once but usually **multiple times daily** to see if I can contribute.  This behavior makes me ideal for a moderator position because I check frequently and am eager to take action if I'm able.

Answer (score 4):

I nominate myself as a moderator for our community.

---

[profile for Oliver Salzburg on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/95447.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/95447)


[image: profile for Oliver Salzburg at Raspberry Pi, Q&A for users and developers of hardware and software for Raspberry Pi]


[image: profile for Oliver Salzburg at Raspberry Pi Meta, Q&A about the site for users and developers of hardware and software for Raspberry Pi]

---

I like to believe that, over the past months, I've become an active contributor to [superuser.com](http://superuser.com). I hope I've picked up many valuable lessons from the moderators over there about what is required from a moderator.

I am still desperately waiting for my own Raspberry Pi and hardly consider myself a valuable contributor in regards to questions and answers.

I do, however, read every new question while I'm awake and keep an eye on our tags and chat.

I'm very passionate about StackExchange and the Raspberry Pi as well. Hopefully, you'll give me the opportunity to help keep order within our community.

Answer (score 4):

After a recommendation on chat, I'm nominating myself as well.

---

[profile for ACarter on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1113893.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/1113893/acarter)

[image: profile for ACarter at Raspberry Pi, Q&A for users and developers of hardware and software for Raspberry Pi]


[image: profile for ACarter at Raspberry Pi Meta, Q&A about the site for users and developers of hardware and software for Raspberry Pi]

---

I may not have the most Rep, or have given the most answers or whatever, but I'm certainly active enough.

I believe I do exibit all the traits required to be a moderator.

I can keep a cool head. An answer of mine was recently offensively commented, and I just flagged the commment and asked the commenter to stop being rude and tell me how I could improve the answer. (Okay your 'perfect moderator' might have just ignored it, but I've **learnt from the experience** and will know what to do better next time)

I have done a load of editing, and **I'm not scared to dig in and try and help**.

A few words on other sites. I have experience over on Stack Overflow, I'm an administrator over on a fairly high profile wiki at [wikia.com](http://wikia.com), and have experience with moderation/administration/whatever on other similar systems.

I am obviously not all amazing though, we all have things we could do better with. For example, I recently asked a question that received quite 4 close votes in a short space of time. But after hearing an explanation, I saw why, and ended casting the final close vote myself.

It's probably not very good for my social life, but if I see a list of flags waiting to be reviewed, or similar, I will not stop reviewing them until there are none left (or I've used up all my internet usage and am about to be cut off).

Answer (score 2):

I would like to nominate myself as a pro-tem moderator:

[image: profile for Jon Egerton on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

I would make it clear that I'm not the most experienced RPi user (or even linux), however this is not what I'm bringing to the table here:

Over on SO I have both the Copy Editor (1018 reviews, and 698 revisions) and Marshall badges (516 helpful flags raised and only 1 declined).

Out of the year and 5 months I've been a member on SO, I've visited on 429 days (jeez I need a holiday).

My experience of what makes a good question on an SE site should help the RPi site succeed in its beta phase.

Finally, the other element that I feel will be useful, is that I'm a good representative of what a lot of the RPi site users will be - people with maybe little / no hardware or linux experience. I bought my RPi to help fill knowledge gaps in these areas. From this standpoint I can help keep the RPi site useful for a lot of the users who will visit, and balance up the more experienced users/mods, using my wider technical experience to bridge the gap between the new users and the experts.